# function return two values

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how effective is this function and if there are any situations when I can use it.  Thanks for any answers.

```
function sum_and_dif(a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    var d = a - b;
    return c +" " + d;
}

var result = sum_and_dif (200, 10);

document.write(result +"</br>");

var where_is_a = result.indexOf(" ");// Here i detected where is the empty space
var c_number = parseInt(result.substring(0, where_is_a));
var d_number = parseInt(result.substring(where_is_a +1,result.length));

document.write(c_number +"</br>");
document.write(d_number +"</br>");
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be more useful to use an object as a return value, instead of a string.

```
return { sum: c, diff: d };
```

This way, you can easily use it by typing `result.sum` or `result.diff`.

Comment: thanks, I read more here [link](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmultir.htm)

Comment: @joni I wouldn't recommend any of the other 2 solutions proposed by your link as I think global variable or arrays are not meant to be used that way. I'll prefer to stick with the object instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return more than one value, you're pretty much looking at an array or object:

```
function sum_and_diff(a, b) {
    …
    return { sum : c, diff : d };
}

var foo = sum_and_diff(1, 2);
alert(foo.sum);
alert(foo.diff);
```